# Does a Ugandan need a visa to transit in Armsterdam?

Tags: visas

I'm a Ugandan going to Ecuador, transiting in Amsterdam. Do I need a visa?

Answer (score 0):

Subject to certain conditions you may be able to transit without a visa.

From [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx)

> Transit - Netherlands (NL)
>
> Visa required.
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Passengers arriving from a non-Schengen
>   Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight on the same
>   aircraft or for the first connecting flight to a third country which
>   is not a Schengen Member State. They must:
>
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.